# Crazy characters - trying to insert into UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm trying to create a script that copies data from an old legacy mysql database into my new utf-8 formatted database.

One particular field is causing me trouble, its a latin1 field - and one record has the following in it:

`!-#$%'&*Â£Â¥`

When the update is performed, I get the following error message:

`Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xA3' for column 'messageContent' at row 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\
library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 234`

Now, I'd like to strip characters that cause a problem, but other than checking `ord($character) <= 126` I don't know what to do. I'm worried that my method might lose valuable data.

I am using MySQL 5.1.43 on Windows 7 - with PHP 5.3.1

Comment: Howeverm must be something to do with PHP as I can run this query in MySQL directly:

INSERT INTO collectedData
(messageContent)
VALUES
("!-#$%'&*Â£Â¥");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem with a function deeply nested in some classes that was the problem....

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to convert your database? If so read [this link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,25921,177553#msg-177553) that should give you some tips on converting it, and there is a script there that might work.

Comment: No, I'm trying to copy fields from one table to another. The source table is written by someone else, and I cannot change it.